# How trigger an animation only when element is on a certain position of screen?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

I'm using [react-reveal](https://www.react-reveal.com/), I would trigger animations only when element are on middle screen or other position. How do that? I'm new in css animation, I'm supposing I have to display the component only on specific position in screen with CSS then the magic will happen,

meanwhile, thanks for any hints

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-waypoint](http://brigade.github.io/react-waypoint/) and set your own css animation or call a function

Comment: thanks I will checkout if it possible to use it for detect y position of the React element